# How to substitute synchronization context / task scheduler to another one inside TaskCompletionSource.Task for ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

Assume I created a library containing such method:

```
Task MyLibraryMethodAsync()
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    Action myWorkItem =
        () =>
        {
            // Simulate some work.
            // Actual work items depend on input params.
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
        };

    // The next two lines is simplification for demonstration.
    // I do not have access to the workerThread - it is created
    // and managed for me by another lib.
    // All I can do - is to post some short work items to it.
    var workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myWorkItem));
    workerThread.Start();

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Any user of my lib can call `MyLibraryMethodAsync` like this

```
await MyLibraryMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
VeryLongRunningMethod();
```

```cs
void VeryLongRunningMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
}
```

And here the problem comes – `VeryLongRunningMethod` will be executed inside the `taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null)` call and thus it will block `workerThread` for a long period of time, which is not desired behavior because `workerThread` is intended to run small portions of code (work items).

How do I substitute context / scheduler to a **thread pool** inside the returned task making `await x.ConfigureAwait(false)` to continue on the **thread pool**, but not on the `workerThread`?

The current solution I found is

```
Task MyLibraryMethodAsync()
{
    // ...

    return taskCompletionSource.Task
        .ContinueWith(x => x.Result, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

However, I do not like it due to overhead it creates.
May be more elegant solution exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of .NET 4.6 there is an option in `TaskCreationOptions` called `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`, which does exactly what you want, it ensures that all continuations are run asynchronously, rather than run synchronously when setting the result.  `TaskCompletionSource` has an optional `TaskCreationOption` parameter in its constructor for you to provide that option.

If you're using an earlier version of .NET you'll need to do a less efficient hack, such as adding another continuation, as you showed, or explicitly setting the result in a thread pool thread, rather than through the callback action.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can explicitly create a background task to avoid blocking:

```
await MyLibraryMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await Task.Run(() => VeryLongRunningMethod());
```

You can even leave out the ConfigureAwait then:

```
await MyLibraryMethodAsync()
await Task.Run(() => VeryLongRunningMethod());
```

EDIT: Based on your comment: If you as the author of the library want to prevent blocking the Thread, you can use:

```
Task.Run(() => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null));
```

Comment: From the user point of view, you are right. But I’m lib developer and I need to make sure that lib users won’t block the worker thread anyhow.

Comment: See EDIT - what about using Task.Run(() => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null)); to set the result?

Comment: This gives the same overhead as my current solution. Anyway, Servy solved my problem.